# How Kubernetes connecting external mysql from fix ip

Tags: service, external, kubernetes

I know how to create the service abstraction that points to an endpoint to an external database(not within the cluster ip). However, my mysql service (single host mysql) only permits fix ip for access. The obvious reason is security.

So, how can one fix this?

```
  kind: "Service"
  apiVersion: "v1"
  metadata:
    name: "example-external-service"
  spec:
    ports:
      -
        name: "mysql"
        protocol: "TCP"
        port: 3306
        targetPort: 3306
        nodePort: 0
```

end point defintion:

```
kind: "Endpoints"
apiVersion: "v1"
metadata:
  name: "example-external-service" 
subsets: 
- addresses:
  - ip: "10.10.1.1"
  ports:
  - name: "mysql"
    port: 3306
```

Comment: Can you clarify: 'my mysql service (single host mysql) only permits fix ip for access'. Is this to say your mysql server has a whitelist IP range for allowable clients?

Comment: Does granting permissions to all kubernetes node ips do the trick?

Comment: Yes, the node ips can be the whitelist ip range. Will the tcp packet be nat to the nodeip as the it reach out the mysql?

Comment: Has anyone had any similar experience?

Comment: yes, they'll be NATed.